# How to handle enter key press in field written to CSV file?

Tags: java, android, csv

I am currently working in`android studio`. I have an input form activity, which is written to a `CSV` file on submit, which is then added as an attachment for an email. In a particular field, if I press the Enter key, to create a new line - the `CSV` file format is disturbed (but I need to be able to press enter in the field)

Comment: What do you mean by "the CSV file format is disturbed"? What is the output?

Comment: I have tried this and no success

Comment: When I send the email, the csv file is okay until the field with the linebreak in it is added, it goes onto a new line

Comment: ID  DATE  TIME  STAFF  ANIMAL  ITEM  DETAIL
'1' '11/12/2017' '18:25' 'Rob' '546506504650' 'Item' 'Details'
'2' '3/12/2017' '12:20' 'Adam' '640698046984' 'Item 2' 'Detail 2'
'6' '13/12/2017' '16:37' 'John' '065464616684' 'Health Check' 'lkduhfglaiugfrhiolsfg
kfydgwyiegfiyuegfisgf'

Answer (score 0):

Try handling Shift Enter (alt-enter like in excel) for new line in a text area.

Comment: I will not be the person entering information to the sqlite database